# DAX: Calculate Average for Quarterly Data (calculated using COUNT measure)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

DAX professionals,

Is there a way to calculate average of quarters (per year) using DAX (and not Excel formula).

[image]

I am a DAX newby, so any help and/or advise is appreciated

Comment: Is this your sample raw data? if not, show how your raw data is structured in the table. Are Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 measure?

Comment: thanks mkRabbani. I managed to figure it out in the meantime by using DAX DIVIDE() function. :)